# Extract multiple values from xml column using postgres

Tags: xml, postgresql, xpath

I have an XML column that contains thousands of rows. Each row contains the xml representation of a metadata file.

How do I extract multiple xml fields from each row?
I guess I need to use xpath (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-xml.html), but the given examples are not enough for me to understand it.

Let's assume there's this in a row called "data" in the table "xml":

```
> <gmd:MD_Metadata xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd"
> xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco"
> xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
> xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
> xmlns:geonet="http://www.fao.org/geonetwork"
> xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
> xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd
> something.com/schemas/inspire/gmd/gmd.xsd">
> <gmd:contact>
>     <gmd:CI_ResponsibleParty>
>       <gmd:organisationName>
>         <gco:CharacterString>Something</gco:CharacterString>
>       </gmd:organisationName>
>       <gmd:contactInfo>
>         <gmd:CI_Contact>
>           <gmd:address>
>             <gmd:CI_Address>
>               <gmd:electronicMailAddress>
>                 <gco:CharacterString>something@something.com</gco:CharacterString>
>               </gmd:electronicMailAddress>
>             </gmd:CI_Address>
>           </gmd:address>
>         </gmd:CI_Contact>
>       </gmd:contactInfo>
>     </gmd:CI_ResponsibleParty>   
> </gmd:contact>
```

How do I get the organisationName and the electronicMailAddress for all rows in the xml column? What would the query look like as a select statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should do the trick:

```
SELECT
    (xpath('//gmd:organisationName/gco:CharacterString/text()',t1,'{{gmd,http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd},{gco,http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco}}'))[1]::text,
    (xpath('//gmd:electronicMailAddress/gco:CharacterString/text()',t1,'{{gmd,http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd},{gco,http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco}}'))[1]::text
FROM xml,
    LATERAL unnest((
        SELECT
            xpath('//gmd:contact',data,'{{gmd,http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd}}')
    )) t1;
```

I examine all rows of `xml` and for each of them I run a `LATERAL` subquery to extract all contacts. Then for each contact I extract the `organisationName` and `CharacterString` fields. Unfortunately, the query is bit long because of all the namespace stuff.

Comment: It works well, if you limit the nested select query by adding LIMIT 1, otherwise it returns more than one row, causing the query to fail. Since the database contains standardised metadata every single record contains a field that's called "gmd:contact"

Comment: @stopopol Yes, you are right. I rewrote the query with a `LATERAL` subquery, so that it has not problems with the multiple rows. It will not extract the fields from all rows.